# Invalid argument for appscript UrlFetchApp.fetch

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script, facebook-fql

I'm trying to fetch data from the facebook FQL api using google appscript.  Unfortunately, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error encountered: Invalid argument: https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+post_id,share_info,comment_info,like_info,created_time+FROM+stream+WHERE+post_id+IN+(SELECT+post_id+FROM+stream+WHERE+source_id='SOME_SOURCE_ID'+AND+created_time+>+1369869370+AND+created_time+<+1377645370+ORDER+BY+created_time+DESC+LIMIT+0,100)&access_token=XXXXXXXXX
```

If I copy/paste the url into my browser, I get a valid JSON response which makes me think that the url is valid, however, if I look at the execution transcript, it points me to the `var postfetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(...)` line.

Here's my code.

```
var posturl = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+post_id,share_info,comment_info,like_info,created_time+FROM+stream+WHERE+post_id+IN+" +
              "(SELECT+post_id+FROM+stream+WHERE+source_id='" + source + "'+AND+created_time+>+" + istartEpoch.toString() + 
              "+AND+created_time+<+" + iendEpoch.toString() + "+ORDER+BY+created_time+DESC+LIMIT+0,100)&access_token=" + token;

var postfetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(posturl);
var postjson = postfetch.getContentText();
var postdata = Utilities.jsonParse(postjson);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `<` and `>` aren't valid characters to put into a url.  Changing them to `%3E` and `%3C` and now all is right with the world.